# How can i clear this error code: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'MachAr'?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to import a Pyrolite.plot but i have been getting these error messages:  module 'numpy' has no attribute 'MachAr' please how can i solve this

I tried to import pyroplot from pyrolite.plot but i keep getting the error message: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'MachAr

Comment: According to the numpy release notes the numpy.MachAr class has been deprecated in numpy 1.22 (https://numpy.org/doc/stable/release/1.22.0-notes.html). Downgrading to versions before 1.22 might help. :)